# How to convert logical statements into their opposites?

Tags: logic

I have a scenario where I am checking whether to hide something depending on multiple variables values. For some these statements, if they evaluate to true, then I will skip over showing something (showing by default). However, I need to re-write my statements so that if they evaluate to true, then I will show something (hiding by default).

For Example:

```
If X !== 1 && Y !==1
```

For Example:

```
If X === 3 or Y === 3
```

If either example were true, then I would skip (hide) something.

I need to flip conditions the conditions written in the code so that the expressions are their opposites. I cannot just evaluate the original expression and then swap the end true/false result.
Would

```
X === 1 or Y === 1
```

And

```
X !== 3 && Y !== 3
```

Be the logical opposites respectively? How can I approach re-writing these expressions so that they would evaluate to their opposite result every time?

I cannot simply do !(If X !== 1 && Y !==1) in this situation. Would De Morgan's law be applicable to what I am trying to do? I'm considering just flipping all "===" to "!===" (and vice versa) and flipping all "ands/ors" so that I can get the results I want. This seems to work in cases I've tried, however I am not sure whether it would be working in "all" cases. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is *exactly* DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I follow what you're asking the inverse of

```
If X !== 1 && Y !==1
```

is:

```
if (X == 1 || Y == 1)
```

which is the same as:

```
if !(X !== 1 && Y !==1)
```

Here's how to think about it: In your example, both X and Y must not equal 1 to be true; therefore if either X or Y equal 1 the statement is false. Now convert that last sentence to boolean.

When inverting a logical statement, invert the arguments and the logical condition: "and" becomes an "or" and vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to negate the whole condition, the simplest way to do it is to just wrap the entire expression in `!`.

For example the following conditional clause:

```
If X !== 1 && Y !== 1
```

can be flipped by replacing it with:

```
If !(X !== 1 && Y !== 1)
```

Now, this is perfectly correct, but it may seem rather ugly to you. This is where DeMorgan's laws can be applied, to rewrite the expression in an *equivalent*, but possibly syntactically simpler form.

DeMorgan's laws state that:

- `!(x && y) === !x || !y`, and that
- `!(x || y) === !x && !y`.

So we can for example take our ugly (but correctly flipped) conditional clause above:

```
If !(X !== 1 && Y !== 1)
```

and use the first of DeMorgan's laws listed above to rewrite it (without changing the meaning at all):

```
If !(X !== 1) || !(Y !== 1)
```

and then by simple reasoning (`!(a !== b)` is equivalent to `!(!(a === b))` is equivalent to `a === b`):

```
If X === 1 || Y === 1
```

and this is (also) a flipped version of the original clause `If X !== 1 && Y !== 1`.